# Handling multiple web apps under a unique Firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a Firebase project holding a few Hosting sites (web apps).

It works as I wish, but I want to clean up the way I switch between the sites.

For that, I can find some information on the net; but here is one thing I need to know and did not find much:

I have two sites https://appone.web.app/ and https://apptwo.web.app/; they share 99% of the code, but:

For the first one I use this code in a source file called tools.js:

```
....
let appVar = "the-app-for-Peter"
let localAppNbr = 194
let appName = 'appone'
....
```

For the second one the code has to be:

```
....
let appVar = "the-app-for-Susy"
let localAppNbr = 749
let appName = 'apptwo'
....
```

And I also have a file called appFunctions.js containing implementations for three functions:

appFnOne(), appFnTwo() and  appFnThree().

Since the function implementations are different for the two sites, I need to have two files:
appFunctions.js for https://appone.web.app/ and app2ndFunctions.js for https://apptwo.web.app/

As one can see the differences are limited and I can take care of that by hand.
Nevertheless this is obviously not a good solution.

How can I handle that situation following good practices?
Since most of the code is the same I only want to keep one local project.

In the case of tools.js, can I write code (only once) taking the name of the app into account?

And in the last case, is there some configuration I can do to tell firebase which file to use (to get the correct implementations) appFunctions.js or app2ndFunctions.js?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting does not offer any sort of per-site configurations that you can customize.  There are no "best practices" provided by Firebase.  It's up to you to manage your configurations as you see fit.  Any sort of "best practice" here is a matter of opinion, perhaps suggested by whatever JS framework or build tools you're using to build your site.

The only thing that could be considered a per-site config is the [reserved URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls) that provides Firebase project information.

```
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

But that might not load all the information you want.  Maybe you could just [examine the URL that's been loaded into the browser](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) using `window.location`, and use that string to select whatever site config you want at runtime.

Comment: I see. if there is no "best practices" then is there a least a way to do what I want?
Other than doing the adjustment by hand each time I go from one site to another.

Comment: The last sentence contains my suggestion. Use the URL to select any configurations at runtime.